# bootstrap.js interferes with radio button D3 selections

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bootstrap-4

I am trying to trigger an event on radio input changes using d3. It seems that, if I use the bootstrap btn-group radiobutton scheme (as seen below) with bootstrap.js, it interferes with the d3 selection.

```
<div id="selector" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle btn-group-lg" data-toggle="buttons" role="group">
<label class="btn btn-secondary active">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_test" id="set1" value="1" checked> 1
</label>
<label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_test" id="set2" value="2"> 2
</label>
<label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_test" id="set3" value="3"> 3
</label>
</div>
```

With the D3 selection:

```
d3.selectAll('input[type="radio"][name="radio_test"]')
    .on('change',function() {
    console.log(this.value);
  })
```

[An example of the problem can be found at this JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/dcohen/ne21v8ya/17/). Removing the bootstrap.js file does make the d3 selection work, however the button toggling provided by bootstrap is removed.

For now, I can just use a JQuery selector, but it would be nice to be able to use d3. Is it possible to get this working using d3 selections?